# Test for shuffling code

Tags: c, shuffle

I am testing some code I wrote to shuffle elements of an array.  While not a real "professional test", I was wondering about the results.
 I generated a random array and kept shuffling it until the array is sorted. I expected the number of times to get the sorted order, to be around n!/2 and maximum shuffles needed to be around n!, where n is the number of elements in the array.

With 5 elements, number of shuffles averages to around 108 and with 6 to around 615.
I was surprised to see that certain shuffles took more that 500 times even if I had only 5 elements.

My question is that, is there a explanation for this result, and/or is my reasoning for the expected shuffles correct?
My shuffle code

```
void shuffle(int* array, int length)
{
    int i=0;
    int r =0;
    for(i=0;i<length;i++)
    {
        r = randomInRange(0,i);
        swap(array,i,r);
    }
}
```

Comment: That's the (in)famous [bogosort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bogosort).

Comment: The sorted order is one in n! possible orders. If the shuffle produces every ordering with equal probability 1/n! the number of shuffles required to sort has [geometric distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_distribution) with expected value n!.

Comment: The worst case is unbounded.It is also possible that the performance depend on the distribution of the random numbers.

Comment: From the wikipedia article on bogosort, average case performance is O((n+1)!). Why it is so, I dont know

Comment: [Sorting the Slow Way](http://www2.tcs.ifi.lmu.de/~gruberh/data/fun07-final.pdf) analyzes randomsort in-depth.

Comment: @pmg this is not the bogosort, it's the bozosort, as you would know, if you would have read the article you have linked.

Comment: @KlausPrinoth there is no check if the array is sorted after each swap, so the code so it is not bozosort. Read the code carefully ;)

Comment: wait... wtf is 'Quantum Bogosort' on that wiki!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why n!/2? The number of permutations is n!, so after n! shuffles you would only expect to have the numbers correctly ordered once. There is no maximum number of shuffles — with 5 cards, you have a 119/120 chance of getting a non-ordered result at each iteration, and this could go on for a very long time.

Here's the output of a Python script I wrote to count the number of times it took to correctly guess a random number from 1 to 120:

```
[17, 43, 251, 72, 4, 10, 41, 61, 74, 22, 172, 49, 43, 66, 994, 99, 59, 88, 255, 48]
```

The average value is 123.4, which is pretty much as expected, but even in this small sample set, the individual values range from 4 to 994.

<s>However, in your case, the results are slightly different. This is because you're using a shuffling algorithm that gives skewed results. [(Jeff Atwood has written a useful blog post on the subject.)](http://blog.codinghorror.com/the-danger-of-naivete/)</s>

I suggest you use the [Fisher-Yates algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle) instead.

Comment: My mistake was in in assumption that the array would be sorted in n! tries. If this was so, n!/2 would have been a valid assumption. The shuffling code I used is supposed to be the knuth-fisher-yates algorithm

Comment: @jogabonito Sorry, my mistake. Your shuffling function is fine. You can start iterating `i` from 1, though, since there's not much point swapping `array[0]` with itself every time.